# Unterschied zwischen „unterbinden“ und „verhindern“

Tags: difference

Aus meiner Sicht, haben diese Wörte die gleiche Bedeutung. Es scheint nur, dass „unterbinden“ in formelleren Kontexten verwendet wird. Ist das der Fall oder gibt's sonstige Unterschiede?

*„mit Klebstoff verhindern, dass eine Schraube locker wird“*

*„unterbinden, dass jemand ohne Fahrkarte in die U-Bahn kommen kann“*

Könnte man ebenso *„unterbinden, dass eine Schraube locker wird“* oder wäre das falsch?

Comment: Please check out the edit - the original version could be read as „orgasm in the subway without a ticket“.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Meiner Meinung bzw. meinem Sprachgefühl nach gibt es einen subtilen Unterschied zwischen "verhindern" und "unterbinden":

"Verhindern" bedeutet, dass man ein Geschehen gar nicht erst eintreten lässt, wohingegen "unterbinden" bedeutet, dass man den Fortgang eines *sich bereits ereignenden* Geschehens verhindert.

Also kann man

> verhindern, dass die Schraube locker wird

und

> die (weitere) Lockerung der Schraube unterbinden

Answer (score 6):

1. *unterbinden* geht nicht mit "dass":

   Er verhindert, dass ich gehe.
   <s>Er unterbindet, dass ich gehe.</s>
2. Man kann nur einen Vorgang *unterbinden*, nicht jedoch das Ergebnis:

   Er verhindert den Fluchtversuch.
   Er unterbindet den Fluchtversuch.

   Er verhindert ein Unglück.
   <s>Er unterbindet ein Unglück.</s>
3. Ansonsten sind die beiden Wörter bedeutungsgleich.

Comment: There is one example where one could use "Er unterbindet, dass ich gehe", namely if it is done by authority instead of taking action. For example if a policeman tells me not to leave the scene, than he "unterbindet, dass ich gehe", but because he is only telling and not gripping my arm he does not "verhindern, dass ich gehe".

Answer (score 1):

Meinem Sprachgefühl nach würde ich "unterbinden" nur verwenden, wenn es darum geht eine Handlung durch Personen zu verhindern. Davon zu sprechen z.B. die Lockerung einer Schraube zu unterbinden klingt für mich komisch.

Entscheidend ist für mich dass eine bewusste Handlung verhindert wird. Bei einer Handlung durch ein Tier würde ich das Wort auch nicht unbedingt verwenden.

Außerdem impliziert "unterbinden" nach meinem Gefühl dass dies bewusst und nach dem Willen des Verhindernden geschieht. Man kann auch versehentlich Geschehnisse verhindern obwohl man das nicht wollte, "unterbinden" passt dann nicht.